# Esperar resposta de um método para prosseguir

Tags: c#, popup

Tenho o seguinte problema, estou fazendo um popup para exibir na tela informações, quase da mesma maneira que um `ShowDialog()`, sendo desta maneira:

```
GeneralPopUp popupErro = new GeneralPopUp("Titulo", "Mensagem");
GeneralPopUp.ACTION_TYPE at = popupErro.ShowPopUp(parent);
```

E minha intenção é, esperar a ação dele dentro do popup que é um `Form` para depois validar oque foi feito da seguinte forma:

```
switch (at)
                {
                    case GeneralPopUp.ACTION_TYPE.NULO:
                        break;
                    case GeneralPopUp.ACTION_TYPE.OK:
                        break;
                    case GeneralPopUp.ACTION_TYPE.FECHAR:
                        break;
                    case GeneralPopUp.ACTION_TYPE.EXTRA1:
                        break;
                    case GeneralPopUp.ACTION_TYPE.EXTRA2:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
```

Mas da maneira que estou fazendo, ele não espera as ações ocorrerem dentro desse form para depois entrar no meu switch, provavelmente terei de fazer um handler pra essa situação.

Qual a melhor maneira para fazer esse handler? Caso não seja, qual uma outra solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal seria mostrar o popup como diálogo modal. Se isso não é possível devido a alguma lógica que você precise específica do método `ShowPopUp` dessa classe, o jeito é apelar.

Bloqueie o formulário pai (desabilite ele sem medo!). Impeça também que o formulário seja fechado, cancelando o evento [`FormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) na marra se necessário (o `Closing` é obsoleto).

Daí é só uma questão de tratar o mesmo evento no popup. Quando ele estiver a ser fechado, verifique o estado dos controles dele e aplique sua logica. Isso é inclusive uma boa prática de programação.

O evento `FormClosing` te passa um parâmetro do tipo [`FormClosingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). Essa classe tem uma propriedade interessante. `Cancel` permite que você cancele o fechamento de um formulário, basta colocar seu valor como falso dentro do método que trata o evento. Daí se a logica não validar alguma coisa você pode impedir que o popup seja fechado facilmente.

**Edit:** vendo que o seu `GeneralPopUp` é um `Form`, basta executar o switch dentro do evento que eu descrevo acima. Dessa forma, tanto faz se o formulário foi aberto via `Show` ou `ShowDialog`. Abrindo como dialogo não precisa nem se esforçar pra bloquear o formulário pai. Boa sorte aí!

Comment: eu que fiz ela, ela é minha.

Comment: mas dessa maneira eu consigo fazer com que meu código espere a resposta desse popup para continuar?

Comment: Sim. Se o popup for aberto como diálogo, o controle só volta pro formulário pai quando o diálogo for fechado. E antes de ser fechado, ele necessariamente dispara o evento `FormClosing`. Lembre-se: você vai tratar o evento `FormClosing` do formulário popup, não do pai.

Comment: excelente!!!!!!